# Getting error information from $http.get and $http.jsonp requests

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm trying to call an endpoint using `$http.get` but the call fails each time. The error status just returns `-1`.

How can I get a more detailed error message?

Maybe I'm making some mistake in my JavaScript but I seem to be able to call other end points fine. The request that fails for me is:

```
$http.get("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/security/currency/cross-rates/EUR,AUD")
    .success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
        return data;
    }).error(function (status){
        alert("Error status : " + status);
    });
```

Comment: status -1, is the connection is off, check your network connection, it is not the response from server, is not calling to server.

Comment: Hi @Nasreddine, thank you for the response. I get json data back from the same endpoint via my browser and a c# httpweb request console app but only -1 from the angular http get. I would have expected error responses too in console app and browser if it was a connection issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnConroy See my answer below.

Comment: Please note that `success` and `error` is deprecated! Use `then` instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Bloomberg API doesn't include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in their response. This makes it impossible for an Angular web based app to access the API since most browsers respect [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is a CORS issue as Nasreddine suggested then you can use a CORS plugin in google chrome for testing purposes. It will get resolved when you host it in a server.

Coming to your Question a response of -1 usually indicates a timeout of request/ Server not responding.